# Remove year from date string?

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

I'm using the NSDateFormatter to get a string representing the date from my NSDate:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
return [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

The `NSDateFormatterFullStyle` format is like *Tuesday, April 12, 1952 AD*. I can easily check if this date is the same year as now (using [NSDate-Extensions](https://github.com/erica/NSDate-Extensions)). If this is the case, I would like the part of the string representing the year to be removed. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any solutions for this. I end up searching the string for a year and remove it if it exists.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a good article on what you're looking for: [Date and Time Examples for iOs](http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/date-and-time/date-and-time-examples)

Comment: Are you thinking of the ´setDateFormat´ method as well?

Answer (score -1):

Yes:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, MMMM d"];
```

`EEEE` represents the day of the week, `MMMM` represents the month, and `d` represents the day of the month.

Comment: This is not as useful as using the `NSDateFormatterStyle` as this takes the device's region in notice.

Comment: Ah. Well I can't think of another solution, unless you want to hardcode format styles for all locales available.